# Java Android Camera

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have this simple camera intent app but I want to know how to add filters to it. I am a beginner in Java I followed a guide to make the camera work. Can anyone help me on how to add filters with buttons onClick activity?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private static String logtag = "CameraApp";

private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

private Uri imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button cameraButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_camera);

    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
}


private OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        takePhoto(v);
    }
};

public void takePhoto(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "pic.jpg");

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));

    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);

    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;

            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_camera);

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {

                bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch(Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(logtag, e.toString());
              }
          }
        }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implement effects like this:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Docu:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#EFFECT_AQUA

```
Update:

 Button filterbutton;  
Button filterbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.filterbutton); }

       filterbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 


             public void onClick(View v) { 

   v.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA); 
}
```

Comment: I know that but how do I integrate it in the code for example when a photo is taken then you can click a button and apply that effect

Comment: In the onClick Method of this button you write something like: v.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA);

Comment: do I add the buttons in the onActivityResult or in the onCreate method?

Comment: In the onCreate method.

Comment: Button aquaButton = (Button)fundViewById(R.id.aqua_button) // gets the button Then I add this right ? Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA);
camera.setParameters(parameters);

Comment: That add the filter when you take the Picture, not on Button click.This should be in the onCreate:Button aquaButton = (Button)fundViewById(R.id.aqua_button), try this (v.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA); )in the onClick of the Button you wan to use to add the filter. That has to be a new button.

Comment: I want to know how to add a filter by clicking a button after the picture has been taken.

Comment: Where does your Picture appear after taking the photo?

Comment: My Picture appears in the middle of the screen. The code above that is my code. I just want to assign effects like aqua, sepia to buttons and when you click them after the image is taken to apply that effect to the image and save it to pictures after the effect is applied.

Comment: Like I said: In the onClick method of the Button which should perform the filter Actions you have to add v.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA); . This is my ideo of solving it.

Comment: Can you give me an example using my code above because I am confused?

Comment: Have a look at my normal answer. I think it should look like this. But I am not sure.

Comment: I dont think that is the case because you can't use many filters with that method.

Comment: Well that´s a lot of work. You better start small. I don´t know too much about cameras, sorry. Experiment with 1 single filter before you go that big.

Comment: I just need 4 filters thats all I just tried what you said but when I add the aqua button in the onCReate and create a listener after my cameralistner is not working

Comment: Have a look here I tried using this but I can't get it to work. http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-tutorial/camera-effects-in-android-development/

Comment: Sorry, that´s all I can do for you.

Comment: I am surprised no one can answer this ...